# Failed to save modifications in Power BI

Tags: cloudera, powerbi

I am trying to generate report in **power BI** for that i am merging two tables.

Tables are getting merged but when i am trying to apply the changes i am getting below error.

[image]

Comment: Can you please add screenshots of your table Structures

Comment: @Sid i can't share my tables as it is confidential. I am having 2 tables all columns are in text format.

Comment: I sympathize, but if you can't help us reproduce the issue, we can't really reliably help. See "[mcve]" for guidance on creating a repro stripped of confidential stuff.

Comment: I believe this is not a Power BI issue, but Cloudera.

Comment: @FoxanNg how you know ?